# No SSH URL in GitHub

Tags: github, ssh, https

### Intro

I hate to type username and pass again and again every time I push to github. So I am using ssh connection, one day trying to clone from github, I found no `use ssh` link on github.

### Problem

How can I re-pop the ssh url on github?

[image: only https]

I have done pub and private key setting already.

Answer (score 3):

Session was out. I was logged out github. Sorry.

Comment: This means, pushing other users rep,  I have to push with username and password e because I cannot get the ssh link without logging in.